# Multi level model in R: error comparing models due to different number of observations

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, error

I am running a linear multi level model in R. 
The predictor variable is called "OAI", and the response variable is called "Ens", I am allowing the intercepts and slopes to vary with "ID".

Here is a visual plot of the data: [image: OAI vs Ens, with ID]

I have built my model up, to see if including slopes and intercepts significantly improves the model.

First a base line model:

```
interceptOnly <-gls(Ens~1, data = d, method = "ML", na.action=na.exclude)
```

Then I allowed intercepts to vary with ID:

```
randomInterceptOnly <-lme(Ens~1, data = d, random = ~1|ID, method = "ML", na.action=na.exclude)
```

Next I added OAI as a predictor

```
randomInterceptOAI <-lme(Ens~OAI, data = d, random = ~1|MusID, method = "ML",na.action=na.exclude)
```

Next I wanted to compare the "randomInterceptOnly" and the "randomInterceptOAI" models to see if the fit has improved now I've added the predictor variable:

```
anova(randomInterceptOnly, randomInterceptOAI)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error: 
[image: error in R]

This is because I have some missing data points for both "Ens" and "OAI" - this means there are different numbers of observations for the "randomInterceptOnly" and  "randomInterceptOAI" models.

Is there a good work around for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is just to specify `dnew <- na.omit(d)` and go from there; this will keep only the complete cases.  Unless you go a fancy route like imputation, there's really nothing you can do to compare fits with `NA`s for a subset of the predictors.

Note that if you have a lot more predictors in your data set, some with `NA`s, `na.omit()` is too blunt an instrument -- the easiest thing to do is to start by selecting the subset of predictors that will go into any of the models to be compared:

```
d.new <- na.omit(d[,c("Ens","OAI","MusID")])
```